# XCP daq list - do ODTs have to be transmitted in increasing order?

Tags: can-bus, xcp

A DAQ list consists of multiple ODTs which are "numbered".

Is it part of the XCP standard that the ODTs in a DAQ list must be transmitted in an ordered manner?

Answer (score 0):

From the section

> 1.3.4 XCP Packet Addressing for DAQ and STIM

of the *XCP Reference Book* available from Vector [here](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/application-areas/ecu-calibration/xcp/XCP_ReferenceBook_V3.0_EN.pdf), there are two ways of addressing packet with DAQ.

Absolute ODT numbers, which requires a transmission in an ordered manner 
Relative ODT numbers, which doesn't.

Comment: `Absolute means that the ODT numbers are unique throughout the entire communication –
i.e. across all DAQ lists.` so why would they need to be transmitted in any order?

Comment: `In turn, this means that the use of absolute ODT numbers assumes a transformation step that utilizes a so­called “FIRST_PID for the DAQ list.If a DAQ list starts with the PID j, then the PID of the first packet has the value j, the second packet has the PID value j + 1, the third packet has the PID value j + 2, etc. Naturally, the Slave must ensure here that the sum of FIRST_PID + relative ODT number remains below the PID of the next DAQ list.` Because you don't specify the relative part while transmitting: first to arrive is +1, second +2, ...